# Approach for a multi-lingual WPF application

Tags: wpf, prism, multilingual

it seems there are a number of approaches on how to implement multiple languages in a WPF application. But I would like some more information about what method I should be using with the following requirements:

- It's a PRISM application, so a number of independent modules (assemblies) working together. I would like that each assembly has its own translations of UI elements.
- I need a simple approach, no tools needed to generate stuff
- Should still be able to use blend to design the UI
- Optionally be able to switch language without restarting the application (not a dealbreaker)

Can someone advice me on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile I found an open source project that works really well: http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com. It's just adding a reference to the dll, adding the resources with translations, and using it in XAML. It worked in 5 minutes. I can add multiple resources to individual modules; and it works fine in visual studio designer and blend. And, locale can be changed on the fly. Meets my requirements :)

Comment: hi there. I am trying to integrae WPFLocalizeExtension into my prism application too. But my app couldnt resolve the resources at runtime. At design time it is fine. Do you have a working example I could have a look at? Thank you.

Comment: You configured the resource files as 'embedded resource'?

Comment: yep. set the the access modifier to publish too,

Comment: I just followed the guidelines of http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Resource%20files&referringTitle=Documentation. You named the resource files correctly? Don't have source code to give because it's part of a bigger company system.

Comment: thank you for the replies. I have fixed my problem by consolidating all rexs files into one and put it in the infrustracture project.

Answer (score 4):

A common approach is to bind the text property of your textblocks / labels etc.. to some property on a statically defined localization resource:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static loc:LanguageContext.Instance}, 
                         Path=Dictionary,  Mode=OneWay,
                         Converter={StaticResource languageConverter},
                         ConverterParameter=TextId}" />
```

i.e. LanguageContext.Instance exposes a dictionary via a property Dictionary, the Converter uses the given ConverterParameter to look up the text identified via TextId.

This is a cumbersome approach, and will not fulfil all your requirements.

A better method is to defined your own markup extension to perform this sort of logic. There are a couple of solutions I have seen on the web, this high rated codeproject article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/realtime_multilingual.aspx

And a similar solution here that provides Blend, on-the-fly language changes, so is probably a good choice for you:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection.aspx

With the above example you define an attached property which identifies the key of the translated item, and use the Translate markup extension to identify the properties which are translated.

NOTE: it is not just text which is being translated here, often you have to change colors / graphics etc ...

Comment: Thanks, the second link seems a nice approach, but I have to adapt it because currently it seems that you can register a resource only one time for each region; and I would need multiple resources per region as each module would register their own resource. I'll have a look to see if it's feasible!